# Google Cloud Storage API: can't generate access token, access denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to Google APIs and I've been trying for days to use a service account to upload content to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I'm able to accomplish this, but only with a temporary access token obtained from the Google API playground, and I need to be able to get new access tokens so the service account can always upload content.

I've been experimenting with the following, but I keep getting access denied, even though the account in question has 'owner' permissions.

```
curl -X POST / -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \ -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \ -d @Documents/request.json \ https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/content-uploader@kol-hatorah-kulah.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken
```

response:

```
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The caller does not have permission", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }
```

When I run `gcloud config list` I get the correct project, and the account is my work email, which is also in Google Cloud as an owner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `curl` command is attempting to use a service account identity to generate an Access Token. The command is failing because you do not have permission.

Add the role **roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator** to the identity running the command.

Comment: Tried this. Got the same error- thanks though.
Edit: it may have actually worked, and just took a minute. Im going to confirm this, and if it works, I'll mark your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidReese - Google Cloud IAM is a global service. It can take a minute or two to propagate changes globally.

Answer (score 4):

> DISCLAIMER - my solution works for *Workload Identity Federation*
> related problems.

I've had hard time with this error, but finally found it!

**For me it was wrong attribute mapping.**

I was following some tutorial (which probably went outdated) and mapping was different than from official github action task documentation (**[here](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#setting-up-workload-identity-federation)**)

I had `repository_owner` and `aud`. Changed it for `repository` and...
**It works!**

To sum up my mapping looks like this:

```
"google.subject"                 = "assertion.sub"
"attribute.actor"                = "assertion.actor"
"attribute.repository"           = "assertion.repository"
```

So if you got here because of same tutorial... you've been served!

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been banging my head on this issue for hours and this solved it.

Comment: @JSTL if you still have this tutorial - it would be great if you'd share this finding in comments there, for future generations. :)
Or just paste link in comment and I'll do it.

Because if I remember well - except this mapping it was pretty helpful tutorial.

Comment: I am using the following `attribute_mapping`:  `"google.subject" = "assertion.sub"
    "attribute.full" = "assertion.repository+assertion.ref"`. I am pretty sure I am performing the call from the specific repo / branch, however it still fails. any ideas?

Comment: @pkaramol I edited my answer to sum up my setup. Hope it does help you :)

Comment: You are right, Google should update their docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions). The link you provided from GitHub was what helped me fix this in the end. Thanks