Using GitHub Actions to authenticate to Google Workload Identity Federation for credentials to use in a Python script
TL;DR How to get and use credentials to interact with Google products in a Python script (using Workload Identity Federation and GitHub Actions). Code at the end of the post.
I worked calluses into my fingers searching around the web for over 8 hours, and wanted to post here with relevant search terms to help the next poor soul.
This was inspired by this answer which saved my life: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72370925/15187444
Specific use case:

I want to run a Python script in a cron job. The script calls the Google API to add lines to a spreadsheet
Google now recommends authenticating with Workload Identity Federation. This makes sense. Keys are created only for the job and then deleted meaning no long-term storage of sensitive API keys

Problem:

The docs are confusing and based on the linked answer above, it looks like many folks are watching a tutorial that seems to be out of date

Solution:

To create the job, you need to enable GitHub Actions, and write a YAML file which coordinates your jobs
This YAML file will authenticate to Google, run your script and then perform any closing actions

There are steps to take (setting up a service account, downloading the proper libraries, etc.) which are fairly straightforward and easy to implement. I'll let you read the docs to do all that setup yourself.
The crucial step:
Google will not recognize your service account if your provider does not have the proper attribute mapping. Setting up a provider is part of the Workload Identity Federation setup docs.
You likely have seen an error like this:
"error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

or this:
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Permission \'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n    "details": [\n      {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",\n        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",\n        "metadata": {\n          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n')

To set the proper attributes, follow the screenshots below:
Edit your provider

The edit page looks like this. Map attributes like you can see in the second screenshot


Another thing to note is that in order to connect, you need to use the identity_pool Class from the google-auth library and NOT the service_account Class. You can see this in the Python script, where we use credentials = Credentials.from_info(key) after importing from google.auth.identity_pool import Credentials
If you use credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(key), you will get this error because the usual service account key has a different shape/schema than the credentials generated by Workload Identity Federation:
raise exceptions.MalformedError(
google.auth.exceptions.MalformedError: Service account info was not in the expected format, missing fields token_uri, client_email.

Code:
Python script to append data to a Google spreadsheet:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.auth.identity_pool import Credentials

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"]

SPREADSHEET_ID = 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID'
RANGE = 'YOUR_RANGE'

f = open(os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"])
key = json.load(f)

def append_to_spreadsheet(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED"):
    credentials = Credentials.from_info(key)
    append_body = {
        "values": values,
        "range": RANGE,
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        }
    try:
        service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=credentials)

        service.spreadsheets().values().append(
            spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
            range=RANGE,
            body=append_body,
            valueInputOption=value_input_option,
        ).execute()

    except HttpError as error:
        print(error)

append_to_spreadsheet([['value1', 'value2']])

YAML file for GitHub Actions to run the jobs:
name: name_of_your_job

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: "projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<POOL_NAME>/providers/<PROVIDER_NAME>"
        service_account: "<enter your service account email>"
        token_format: 'access_token'
    - name: Setup python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with: 
        python-version: '3.11'
    - name: install python packages
      run:
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install requests google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib google-auth
    - name: call google api
      run: python google.py

This is an informational post. I'm hoping to save others hours of pain :)

Issue with Google Drive API Authentication using GitHub Actions
I created my workload identity pool according to the Google GitHub Actions Auth documentation without any service account. Then I tried to connect to Google Drive, which requires an OAuth 2.0 access token. I used the following configuration:
- name: Authenticate with Google Cloud
    uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
    with:
        project_id: 'my-project'
        workload_identity_provider: 'projects/123456789/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/my-provider'

- name: Upload files to Google Drive
    uses: 'Burak-Atak/drive-upload@master'
    with:
      google_credentials_file_path: ${{ env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
      files_to_create: "app.spec"
      drive_folder_id: "242fgdfg345345"
      files_to_update: "requirements.txt"
      file_ids_to_update: "asdas3534fdgg"

However, I got the following error with below code:
def authenticate_google(self):
    credentials, project_id = load_credentials_from_file(
        os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"],
        scopes=[
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
        ]
    )

    return build("drive", "v3", credentials=credentials)

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid Credentials', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'authError', 'location': 'Authorization', 'locationType': 'header'}]">

I realized I should use OAuth 2.0 for the Google Drive API. Then I changed my configuration to this:
- name: Authenticate with Google Cloud
  uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
  with:
    workload_identity_provider: 'projects/123456789/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/my-provider'
    project_id: '<PROJECT_ID>'
    service_account: '<PROJECT_ID>@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    token_format: 'access_token'
    access_token_lifetime: '60s'
    access_token_scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'

- name: Upload files to Google Drive
    uses: 'Burak-Atak/drive-upload@master'
    with:
      google_credentials_file_path: ${{ env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
      files_to_create: "app.spec"
      drive_folder_id: "242fgdfg345345"
      files_to_update: "requirements.txt"
      file_ids_to_update: "asdas3534fdgg"

After this change, I started to get the following error even though I have the Service Account Token Creator and Owner roles in my service account:
google-github-actions/auth failed with: failed to generate Google Cloud OAuth 2.0 Access Token for <PROJECT_ID>@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Solution
I figured out that I should add a service account to my workload pool. Check the "Connected service accounts" part in the Google Cloud Console. If there is no connected service account, you should add one.

